# How to check the physical health of a USB port

Tags: usb, live-usb, hardware-test

I have a hardware board (running Ubuntu 13.10 on it) available with me.
What I need to do is to write a script file (bash scripting) to check whether USB ports on my hardware board are working fine or not.

Can any one please help me how I can proceed taking into consideration with pass and fail conditions?

Comment: Script?! How about the command `lsusb -v`?